# Retrieve the first and last record available depending on dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand how to extract the first and last records available based on dates with the following example:

```
SELECT clientID, AssessmentDate, TotalScore
FROM Client.Assessments
```

For each of the clients (based on their clientID), I am trying to retrieve the TotalScore for their first and last assessment available (based on the AssessmentDate). I deal with lots of assessment entries, and I usually do a pre-post statistical analysis with the first assessment they have, and I compare it to the last assessment available.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Guessing how `AssessmentDate` might be stored, among other things, doesn't help us help you. One approach to the question you didn't include would be to add two `Row_Number()` columns partitioned by `ClientId` and ordered ascending and descending. The value `1` in each column will identify the oldest and newest assessments. Note that they may be the same row.

Comment: Thank you for the doc on posting TSQL questions in a forum. This is my very first StackOverflow question, and it shows lol. I will look into this partitioned procedure as it may be the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to think in two steps. First, prepare the min/max dates for each client. Second, select for rows with these dates.

```
SELECT clientsMaxMin.clientID
    , ca.TotalScore
FROM 
(
    SELECT clientID
        , max(AssessmentDate) as maxDate
        , min(AssessmentDate) as minDate
    FROM Client.Assessments AS c
    GROUP BY c.clientID
) clientsMaxMin  -- prepare a smaller table with max and min dates
JOIN Client.Assessments AS ca  -- from the original table select only rows with min/max values
    ON ca.AssessmentDate = clientsMaxMin.maxDate
        OR ca.AssessmentDate = clientsMaxMin.minDate
```

Comment: Thank you! This is getting me closer to the answer. I wasn't counting on multiple records being available for each date available and it is driving my code crazy. I will test with more restricted data.